# How to print some pages in c#

Tags: c#

there is a program that it should write just number of pages in the paper.
suppose the count = 50

But when I write the code,It goes rapidly and never stop.

here is the code:

```
 private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        RectangleF yek1;
        while(count >= 0)
        {
           e.Graphics.DrawString("12345678901234567890", TitleFont, BlackBrush,yek,TitleStingFormat);

            yek1 = new Rectangle(10, 10, drawWidth, drawHeight);

            e.Graphics.DrawString(count.toString(), TitleFont, BlackBrush, yek1, TitleStingFormat);

            count --;
            e.HasMorePages = true;

        }
            e.HasMorePages = false;
}
```

Thanks if anyone can help me.

I changed the code like above. but It just print "50" that is the first value of counter.

```
 private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {


        // Page Size
        int pageWidth = 830;
        int pageHeight = 1170;

        int BorderWidth, BorderHeight, BorderX, BorderY, drawHeight, drawWidth, drawY1, drawY2, drawX1, drawX2;
        Color BorderColor;
        float BorderLineWidth;

        Font TitleFont;
        Brush BlackBrush, whiteBrush;
        StringFormat TitleStingFormat = new StringFormat();




        // Border

        BorderWidth = pageWidth - 40;
        BorderHeight = pageHeight - 20;
        BorderX = 30;
        BorderY = 25;
        BorderColor = Color.Gray;
        BorderLineWidth = 2;

        drawHeight = 30;
        drawWidth = 400;
        drawY1 = 400;
        drawY2 = 985;
        drawX1 = 100;
        drawX2 = 513;
        int xc = 0;

        int counter = 10;

        TitleFont = textBox1.Font;
        BlackBrush = Brushes.Black;
        whiteBrush = Brushes.White;
        TitleStingFormat = new StringFormat();
        TitleStingFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;


        // draw border
        Pen BorderPen = new Pen(BorderColor, BorderLineWidth);
        Pen linePen = new Pen(BorderColor, 1);
        linePen.DashStyle = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Dash;

        //Rectangles for clearing the paper
 /*       RectangleF one = new Rectangle(BorderX, BorderY, BorderWidth, drawY * 9 + 8);
        RectangleF two = new Rectangle(BorderX, BorderY + 270, BorderWidth, drawY * 9 + 8);
        RectangleF three = new Rectangle(BorderX, BorderY + 540, BorderWidth, drawY * 9 + 8);
        RectangleF four = new Rectangle(BorderX, BorderY + 810, BorderWidth, drawY * 9 + 5);


        RectangleF yek = new Rectangle(drawX1, drawY1, drawWidth, drawHeight);
        RectangleF dow = new Rectangle(drawX2, drawY1, drawWidth, drawHeight);
        RectangleF se = new Rectangle(drawX1, drawY2, drawWidth, drawHeight);
        RectangleF chehar = new Rectangle(drawX2, drawY2, drawWidth, drawHeight);
        */
        //Draw
        RectangleF yek1;
        RectangleF dow1;
        RectangleF se1;
        RectangleF chehar1;
        while(counter >= 0)
        {
       /*     e.Graphics.DrawString("12345678901234567890", TitleFont, BlackBrush, yek, TitleStingFormat);
            e.Graphics.DrawString("12345678901234567890", TitleFont, BlackBrush, dow, TitleStingFormat);
            e.Graphics.DrawString("12345678901234567890", TitleFont, BlackBrush, se, TitleStingFormat);
            e.Graphics.DrawString("12345678901234567890", TitleFont, BlackBrush, chehar, TitleStingFormat);
            */


            yek1 = new Rectangle(drawX1, 10 +(xc * 830), drawWidth, drawHeight);
        //    dow1 = new Rectangle(drawX2, drawY1+ (xc * 830), drawWidth, drawHeight);
        //    se1 = new Rectangle(drawX1, drawY2+(xc * 830), drawWidth, drawHeight);
        //    chehar1 = new Rectangle(drawX2, drawY2+(xc * 830), drawWidth, drawHeight);

            e.Graphics.DrawString(counter.ToString(), TitleFont, BlackBrush, yek1, TitleStingFormat);
        //    e.Graphics.DrawString("12345678901234567890", TitleFont, BlackBrush, dow1, TitleStingFormat);
        //    e.Graphics.DrawString("12345678901234567890", TitleFont, BlackBrush, se1, TitleStingFormat);
        //    e.Graphics.DrawString("12345678901234567890", TitleFont, BlackBrush, chehar1, TitleStingFormat);

        //    counter--;

            counter--;
            xc++;

            e.HasMorePages = true;
          //  MessageBox.Show(xc.ToString());

        }

        e.HasMorePages = false;
    }
```

Comment: Okay, well you can't just "suppose" count is 50. Find out what it actually is, if its looping endlessly it has to be a lot bigger than you think it is. Are you *sure* it's looping endlessly? How do you know? Could it be that your application hangs on one of the lines in the loop instead?

Comment: If you're using uint - which is not cls compliant and you should use int - than it will never be less than zero. So what's the declaration of count?

Comment: Actually There is a textfield that user can set the number of pages.  but for makeing it more clear, I declare it as a const 50.

Comment: I can see the number of pages that goes up

Comment: Look dudes , the whole program is this : there is a textfile that contains 8000 lines that each line has a string with length = 15. I should write 4 codes in one page. Can u Help me???!!!!

Comment: Eh? I seriously doubt you declared it as a const. If it were, you wouldn't be able to call `count--;`. That would result in a compilation error. Again, show the declaration of `count`.

Comment: right dude,sorry, I declared count like this: int count = 50;

Answer (score 1):

You are doing this wrong. What is happening is its printing your 50 pages, then breaks out of your loop. After it breaks out of your loop, `e.HasMorePages` is still set to `true`. So then your application is like "Oh! There are still more pages. Let's print those". So this it runs the `PrintPage` event again and it rinses and repeats.

Set the `e.HasMorePages` property to `false` after you break out of the `while` loop and it should fix your problem.

Comment: I did this:      while (count > 0){  count --;  print sth; e.hasmorepages = true} e.hasmorepages = false;  But it doesn't work :(

Comment: Can't u help me please?

Comment: Hold on. I'm going to try to reproduce the problem on my computer.

Comment: @Massoud Update your OP with the new code. Explain what "doesn't work" means.

Comment: If the OP is trying to print 50 pages, then the while...loop needs to go away and then it's just `e.HasMorePages = count > 0;`

Comment: I just tried my solution and didn't have a problem. The counter counted down to 0, and then the event stop. You need to post more code.

Comment: @Massoud -- Your new code still doesn't have the `e.HasMorePages = false` after the loop.

Comment: @Massoud -- Can you post the code that raises the PrintPage event?

Comment: @Massoud -- [Here it is](http://pastebin.com/qivz446e). I set breakpoints on like 19 and 22. It repeated 50 times, then returned and my program resumed.

Comment: @Massoud - You need to move this line: `int counter = 10;` outside the PrintPage function. Or initialize it in the `BeginPrint` function.

Comment: sorry,it is still just one page

Comment: sorry man,can't u please write whole this program for me,because it's simple but there is more simple problem that I cant handle that(this problem).

Comment: yes,I saw. I copied and pasted it, but it does not work still.

Comment: @Massoud - I guess I'm not understanding what you need. My code works. Can you elaborate on what you are trying to do exactly?

Comment: @icemanind  look,There is 8000 pages. I just want to write the number of the page on the top of papers,without any content. as simple as I said...

Answer (score 0):

This code looks like it will write all iterations of the loop on a single page, and then do it again for the next page.  You probably want to take out the loop:

```
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    RectangleF yek1;

    // Change "while" to "if" here
    if(count >= 0)
    {
       e.Graphics.DrawString("12345678901234567890", TitleFont, BlackBrush,yek,TitleStingFormat);

        yek1 = new Rectangle(drawX1, drawY1 + (xc * 830), drawWidth, drawHeight);

        e.Graphics.DrawString(xc.ToString(), TitleFont, BlackBrush, yek1, TitleStingFormat);

        count --;

        // Set HasMorePages depending on the value of count
        e.HasMorePages = (count >= 0);
        return;
    }

    // No more pages
    e.HasMorePages = false;
}
```

Comment: I did this,but again,same problem, it goes endlessly

Comment: This works for me...  Looks like you still need to remove the while(...) loop.  Notice that I replaced `while` with `if`